# Getting InvalidIdentityPoolConfigurationException when Retriving records from AWS DynamoDB iOS

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have used AWS DynamoDB in my app. i am using AWSDynamoDBObjectMapper for fetching records from database but getting InvalidIdentityPoolConfigurationException every time. i have set poolId and region in info.pilist,

[image]

Following is my code,

**AppDelegate.m**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider *credentialsProvider = [[AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider alloc] initWithRegionType:AWSRegionUSEast1
                                                                                                identityPoolId:IDENTITY_POOL_ID];



AWSServiceConfiguration *configuration = [[AWSServiceConfiguration alloc] initWithRegion:AWSRegionUSEast2
                                                                     credentialsProvider:credentialsProvider];

AWSServiceManager.defaultServiceManager.defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration;

AWSDynamoDBObjectMapperConfiguration *objectMapperConfiguration = [[AWSDynamoDBObjectMapperConfiguration alloc] init];
[AWSDynamoDBObjectMapper registerDynamoDBObjectMapperWithConfiguration:configuration objectMapperConfiguration:objectMapperConfiguration forKey:@"USEast1DynamoDBObjectMapper"];
_dynamoDBObjectMapper = [AWSDynamoDBObjectMapper DynamoDBObjectMapperForKey:@"USEast1DynamoDBObjectMapper"];
return YES;
}
```

**DynamoDBManager.m**

```
+(void)loginWithFaceBook:(NSString*)fbId{

AWSDynamoDBScanExpression *scanExpression = [AWSDynamoDBScanExpression new];
scanExpression.filterExpression = @"facebook_id = :val";
scanExpression.expressionAttributeValues = @{@":val":fbId};

[[AppContext.dynamoDBObjectMapper scan:[dynamo_user class]
                 expression:scanExpression]
 continueWithBlock:^id(AWSTask *task) {
     if (task.error) {
         NSLog(@"The request failed. Error: [%@]", task.error);
     } else {
        // AWSDynamoDBPaginatedOutput *paginatedOutput = task.result;
         NSLog(@"The request sucesss. Result : [%@]", task.result);

     }
     return nil;
 }];
```

}

**MyViewController.m**

```
 [DynamoDBManager loginWithFaceBook:[result valueForKey:@"id"]];
```

Following s my error:

```
The request failed. Error: [Error Domain=com.amazonaws.AWSCognitoIdentityErrorDomain Code=5 "(null)" UserInfo={__type=InvalidIdentityPoolConfigurationException, message=Invalid identity pool configuration. Check assigned IAM roles for this pool.}]
```

Can anyone having idea about the above error? is any configuration missing in above code?

Answer (score 0):

**1. Adding Facebook as an authentication provider in Cognito Console.**

I can see that you are using Facebook for authentication. In AWS Cognito Console, when creating the identity pool, you have to add Facebook App ID under "Authentication Providers" -> "Facebook"

**2. Adding the sufficient permissions and roles.**

Once the pool is created, you have to attach a Role with the Identity pool and the Role should have the sufficient IAM privileges.

For example, if you want to perform a query, the policy document of the role that is attached to the Identity pool should have the following lines:

```
"Action": [
     "dynamodb: Query"
]
```

You have to add the appropriate actions for the DynamoDB operations you want to perform.